# without Error in my code i am getting error in postaman @PostMapping

Tags: postman, spring-tool-suite

I write code for Restful services.in postman when i tried to send a request by using @Postmapping its getting error in postaman

### this is my controller class

public class BookController {

```
private BookRepository bookrepository;

@PostMapping("/addBook")
public String save(@RequestBody Book book)
{
    bookrepository.save(book);
    return "added book with id"+book.getId();
}



@GetMapping("/findAllBooks")
public List<Book> getBooks()
{
return bookrepository.findAll();
}

@DeleteMapping("/delete")
public String deleteBook(@PathVariable int id){
    bookrepository.deleteById(id);
    return "book deleted"+id;
}
}
```

when i send a request to postman by post method at the time i m getting a error like the below

{
    "timestamp": "2019-03-27T12:22:20.319+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/addBook"
}

Comment: Is your BookController class annotated with `@Controller` or `@RestController`?

Comment: @RestController
public class BookController {